# Kendo Export To PDF Unicode Support

Tags: javascript, unicode, kendo-ui, export, kendo-grid

I have been trying to incorporate languages dynamically into the Kendo controls, and have run into a issue with Chinese translations which are stored as a list of Unicodes in Sql Server Database.

### Translations stored in the Database

[image: Chinese translations stored in DB as unicode]

---

It didn't take long to get the Kendo Grid up and running to display these Unicodes in Chinese, through the use of the column `template` attribute:

```
template: '#= Translation #'
```

### Kendo Grid Displaying Translations

[image: Grid displaying transformed Unicode in Chinese]

---

The issue I am having is with the Excel/PDF exports. They do not render the Unicode values, in the same way that the Kendo Grid does through the use of the `template`. Instead they display default font characters:

### PDF Export

[image: Current export to PDF with missing translations]

### CSV Export

[image: Current export to Excel displaying unicode instead of translation]

---

I have tried the following solutions following research on the issue, to no avail:

- Setting the font family of the grid control following [this recommendation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/drawing-dom#configuration-Custom); (which I don't particularly want to do as a matter of consistency with the rest of the site nor do I understand why this would work as the actual Kendo Grid itself is displaying the Chinese characters perfectly):

  ```
  .k-widget {
      font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';
  }
  ```

---

- Setting the column [`encoded`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.encoded) attribute to true:

  ```
  { field: "AnalyteName", title: "Analyte", attributes: { "class": "customKendoGridCell"}, width: "25%", encoded: true, template: '#= TranslationField #' },
  ```

---

- Using [`kendo.template`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview#render-html-encoded-values):

  > If you want to render an encoded HTML value in a template, Kendo UI templates can automatically handle the encoding.

  ```
  template: '#=setFieldName(TranslationField)#'

  function setFieldName(TranslationField) {
      return kendo.template("<div id='box'>#: TranslationField #</div>");
  }
  ```

This appears to display the entire function instead of just the field, perhaps `kendo.template` needs to be used differently in the context of a Kendo Grid column?

[image: Columns displaying kendo template approach]

I have made a [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/icudo/5) to demonstrate the issue with the PDF export.

Comment: were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have never come across the issue of Unicode, still, I know a solution that may help you.

```
.k-grid {
        font-family: "DejaVu Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
    }
```

Use this line in your grid file, as in kendo, **The standard PDF fonts have no support for Unicode characters**.

Comment: Didn't work, and as per question I have already tried setting font-family attributes and don't particularly want to modify the font as it breaks consistency with the rest of the site. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: I think you have to do this at least for the particular page.
Visit this example and click edit, read the Note by kendo.
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/pdf-export @Sandman

Comment: Yes, check my Dojo example in the original question (which was modified from the example you just sent) - it does not work when using unicode values.